# Split string and get array using regExp in javascript/node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am writing js code to get array of elements after splitting using regular expression.

```
 var data = "ABCXYZ88";
 var regexp = "([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{3}d{2})";
 console.log(data.split(regexp));
```

It returns 
[ 'ABCXYZ88' ]

But I am expecting something like
['ABC','XYZ','88']

Any thoughts?

Comment: That is not a regular expression.

Comment: Try `data.match(/^([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{3})(\d{2})$/).slice(1)`. Is your string format fixed? 2 x 3 uppercase letters and 2 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your regex, then matched it against your string and extracted the relevant capturing groups:

```
var regex = /([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{3})(\d{2})/g;
var str = 'ABCXYZ88';
let m = regex.exec(str);
if (m !== null) {
   console.log(m.slice(1)); // prints ["ABC", "XYZ", "88"]
}
```

In your case, I don't think you can *split* using a regex as you were trying, as there don't seem to be any delimiting characters to match against. For this to work, you'd have to have a string like `'ABC|XYZ|88'`; then you could do `'ABC|XYZ|88'.split(/\|/g)`. (Of course, you wouldn't use a regex for such a simple case.)

Comment: This is really good Mike. This is what i expecting. But i though we can do this using split. Anyway this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `regexp` is not a `RegExp` object but a `string`.
2. Your capturing groups are not correct.
3. `String.prototype.split()` is not the function you need. What `split()` does:

```js
var myString = 'Hello World. How are you doing?';
var splits = myString.split(' ', 3);

console.log(splits); // ["Hello", "World.", "How"]
```

**What you need:**

```js
var data = 'ABCXYZ88';
var regexp = /^([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{3})(\d{2})$/;
var match = data.match(regexp);
console.log(match.slice(1)); // ["ABC", "XYZ", "88"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
      var reg = data.match(/^([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{3})(\d{2})$/).slice(1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m5pgpkje/1/